# How to create an index in Liquibase with a column from other table?

Tags: java, sql, liquibase

I want to create an index for an specific sql call in which I join two tables and I don't know how to insert the outer column.

This is what I  currently have:

```
<changeSet id="1234" author="name" >
        <createIndex catalogName="catalog"
                indexName="idx-master"
                tableName="table-a">
            <column name="type"/>
            <column name="id"/>
            <column name="date"/>
        </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

What I'm looking for is something like a tag column in which I can pass the name of the outer column, so it could be like:

```
<changeSet id="1234" author="name" >
        <createIndex catalogName="catalog"
                indexName="idx-master"
                tableName="table-a">
            <column name="type"/>
            <column name="id"/>
            <column name="date"/>
                <column name="date-from-table-b">
        </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Note that an index over different tables is likely a database system specific functionality (I'm not aware of an RDBMS that supports this, but some may). Therefore a) it's unlikely that liquibase supports it with general functionality and b) if you add a custom SQL statement to create that index, your liquibase specification won't be database system independent anymore.

The latter may not be one of the reasons you use liquibase, but **I'd** still **give a redesign of the table structure a thought**. This indicates a design issue. Sometimes it's worthwhile to create a separate table for such special lookups or to store the data joined in general.

The closest you would get with general functionality is to create your index as you already wrote it down in the question and have an additional one-column index on the date in your joined table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with special `liqubiase` tags, but you can always use `<sql>` tag and create it in plain SQL.

As such:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <sql>
        CREATE INDEX some_index ON ...
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: But, how does I create a joined index? I tryed to do a Create Join Index, but it's not possible.

Comment: I don't know, it depends on the database you're using. Perhaps it's possible, perhaps not. But it's definitely not about `liquibase` anymore. Maybe this will help you somehow https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/how-to-index-a-join-result-of-two-or-more-tables-in-order-to-improve-the-perform

Comment: @XiosGD as my answer points out, this is not a general SQL database feature. Some systems might have custom support for that, but I've not encountered a system yet that does. It's typically sufficient to have separate indices on each table that match anyway.